# How to include duplicate markup in every web page

Tags: html

If all my web pages have the same navigation and footer markup, what is the best way of avoid hard-coding this in every page, so if it needs changing it's only changed in one place so as not to have to edit every html file?

Thanks

Comment: How to [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) duplicate markup on every web page

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- Use a [static HTML generator](https://iwantmyname.com/blog/2011/02/list-static-website-generators.html), which will allow you to use template and pure HTML.
- Use [server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) if your server supports them.
- Use [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).
- Use any server side language, and its templating counter part (php, jinja2, django, et. al)

Answer (score 1):

Use the AJAX `load()` method.

```
$('#mysection').load('yourfile.html');
```

Of course the URL can also point to a PHP script etc.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -1):

You should use a server-side solution depending on the technology that are you using (PHP,ASP,etc...)
I think you should take a look at this [link](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html).

Comment: "link only" answers are not terribly helpful.  What if the link goes stale?  You can improve your answer by summarizing the info in the link (leave the link in, of course).